# Issue with reading a char in binary mode, ╡

Tags: c++, ascii

I am having an issue with reading this character from a text file that was written in ios::binary mode. I used the notation `unsigned char (181)` to write it into the file, but when I try to get the decimal value for that with this line

`cout << text[i] << " " << (unsigned int)text[i] << " " << (int)text[i] << endl;`

I get out this..

`╡ 4294967221 -75`

This seems to be happening with all of my values over 127. And that symbol is the correct symbol that corresponds to the number I used, but for some reason when I try to cast it as unsigned int or int I get a wrong number. Is there something special I need to do with the values in the ascii table over 127?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to `unsigned char` first, before converting to `int` (or `unsigned int`).  Apparently, on your system, plain `char` is signed, which means that it takes values in the range `[-128, 127]` (typically, assuming an 8 bit `char`).

Comment: Okay, yeah I just did that and it worked. Thanks for that. I guess that does make sense.